# If $A$ and $B$ are diffeomorphic via $f$ and $u \in L^\infty(A)$. is $u\circ f \in L^\infty(B)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded open domains on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $f:B \to A$ be a diffeomorphism between $A$ and $B$.

Suppose $u \in L^\infty(A)$. Is $u\circ f \in L^\infty(B)$?

I think this is true, I just want to check that I am not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|_\infty}$
$$ \norm{u \circ f} = \mathop{\rm ess\,sup}\limits_{b \in B} \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{u(f(b))}
= \mathop{\rm ess\,sup}\limits_{a\in A} \abs{u(a)} =\norm u. $$
For the $=$ note that a diffeomorphism maps sets of measure zero onto sets of measure zero,

Comment: , because it is locally Lipschitz.